# Extract a substring

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get proper error message which is there in description. But when my debugger enters into `substring` line its getting exited with no reason.

```
$job= submitting the job 2fdab2d5-f09c-4392-953e-8b85f90d76eb ... 
      client version: 10.2.2.0 
      target: cluster 
      stat: simulatelarge 
      skippath: true error submitting job.  
      vcclientexceptions.vcclientexception: [httpstatuscode = 0; description = e_csc_user_syntaxerror: syntax error. expected one of:_all _and ';' ')' ','  
      description: invalid syntax found in the script. 
      resolution: correct the script syntax, using expected token(s) as a guide.... at token [output], line 13 near the ###: 

$descpos = $job.IndexOf("description:")
$resopos = $job.IndexOf("resolution:")

$descmsg = $descmsg.Substring($descpos) 
Write-Host $descmsg
$ferrormsg = $job.Substring($msgpos,$respos+1)
Write-Host $ferrormsg
```

WORKING - CODE:

```
 [string]$Result=$job
            $Result= $Result -Replace "[\{]|(\{)|[\}]|(\})|[\""]|(\"")",''
            $msgpos = $Result.IndexOf(("message:") )           
            $resopos = $Result.IndexOf(("resolution:") )            
            $descpos = $Result.IndexOf(("description:") )                
            $ferrormsg = $Result.Substring($msgpos,($descpos-$msgpos) ) 
            $ferrormsg = $ferrormsg -Replace "(\,)|(\')|(\-)|(\=)",''

            Write-Host $ferrormsg
```

THANKS ALL ,
Replaceing my string is working fine.

Comment: Is `$job` an array of strings or a single string with newlines?

Comment: `$job= submitting the job 2fdab2d5-f09c-4392-953e-8b85f90d76eb ... ` would throw a `CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: No its a string wholly

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$job= "submitting the job 2fdab2d5-f09c-4392-953e-8b85f90d76eb ... 
      client version: 10.2.2.0 
      target: cluster 
      stat: simulatelarge 
      skippath: true error submitting job.  
      vcclientexceptions.vcclientexception: [httpstatuscode = 0; description = e_csc_user_syntaxerror: syntax error. expected one of:_all _and ';' ')' ','  
      description: invalid syntax found in the script. 
      resolution: correct the script syntax, using expected token(s) as a guide.... at token [output], line 13 near the ###:" 

$descpos = $job.IndexOf("description:")
$resopos = $job.IndexOf("resolution:")
$ferrormsg = $job.Substring($descpos,$resopos-$descpos)
Write-Host $ferrormsg
```

Comment: It helps if you explain your answers so others can understand what you're proposing and why.

Comment: Sure,Basically you wanted everything in between ( "description: ") and ("resolution:"),Hence First lets get the index of each of them.And then use Substring(StartIndex,Number of characters after first character).Which is :-$descpos  and $resopos Respectively

Comment: @ChetanKulkarni Thnaks for reply, but here when i enter to $ferrormsg = $job.Substring($descpos,$resopos-$descpos) it is getting Exited.

Comment: It is getting Exited with what messege? @PinkPink

Answer (score 0):

Other solution :

```
$job= @"
submitting the job 2fdab2d5-f09c-4392-953e-8b85f90d76eb ... 
client version: 10.2.2.0 
target: cluster 
stat: simulatelarge 
skippath: true error submitting job.  
vcclientexceptions.vcclientexception: [httpstatuscode = 0; description = e_csc_user_syntaxerror: syntax error. expected one of:_all _and ';' ')' ','  
description: invalid syntax found in the script. 
resolution: correct the script syntax, using expected token(s) as a guide.... at token [output], line 13 near the ###:
"@ 

$Result=$job -split "`n" | ? {$_ -like "*:*"} | %{$_.replace(':', '=')} | ConvertFrom-StringData

$Result.description
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trying this way